# SQL: How to select all parent nodes in Materialized path?

Tags: mysql, tree, hierarchy

The MySQL databse stores tree with the help of materialized path data structure. How to select all parents of the given node?

I use dot '.' as path separator, and database structure includes 'level' field that indicates the depth of a node in the tree.

Lets I have those tree and need all parents of the node 'a.b.d.e':

```
id | path
 a | a
 b |  a.b
 c |   a.b.c
 d |   a.b.d
 e |    a.b.d.e
 f |  a.f
```

The script should return:

```
a
a.b
a.b.d
a.d.d.e (optional)
```

How to do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in the [question posted by @quambo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34065395/1615266). Here it is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ? LIKE id||%
ORDER BY path
```

Insted of '?' it is necessary to place the path to the given node.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 'a.b.d.e' LIKE id||%
ORDER BY path
```