# Get all parents with path in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table like;

```
id | rank | path
---+------+-------
 1 | NULL | NULL
 2 |  1   | /1/2/
 3 |  2   | /1/2/3/
 4 |  2   | /1/2/3/
 5 |  3   | /1/2/3/5/
 6 |  1   | /1/6/
```

Given path from id 5 or id 5, would like to have all parents like;

```
 1 | NULL | NULL
 2 |  1   | /1/2/
 3 |  2   | /1/2/3/
 4 |  2   | /1/2/3/
 5 |  3   | /1/2/3/5/
```

or

```
 1 | NULL | NULL
 2 |  1   | /1/2/
 3 |  2   | /1/2/3/
 4 |  2   | /1/2/3/
```

Have tried the suggestion here [SQL: How to select all parent nodes in Materialized path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783113/sql-how-to-select-all-parent-nodes-in-materialized-path) but without success.

The query I've attempted is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE '/1/2/3/5/' LIKE id||%
ORDER BY path
```

Additionally, I've looked at queries from
 - https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-9902
 - https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql

among others. Can't find something that fits this.

Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at a query?

Comment: @CalebGoodman Just updated the question with an answer to your question.

Comment: maybe % sign needs commas around it?

Comment: In MySQL, that's `CONCAT(id,'%')` - although surely it would be `CONCAT(path,'%')` !?!